# how to create backup form PostgreSQL without console postgresql?

Tags: ubuntu, backup, postgresql

I have a VPS (ubuntu base).

I can not access to console of postgresql. How should I backup from PostgreSQL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `COPY` command dumps out the data of one table to the console.  You can then save this data locally.

### Example:

`COPY country TO STDOUT`

### Reference

[COPY -- copy data between a file and a table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html)